# Method to stop enemies from spawning Unity5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a laser defender game.

Here is the main function responsible for spawning enemies. I have the variable waves set to 3. Then I want to destroy the position of the space ships in order to not allow them to spawn. The issue is when I start the game there are no ships at all.

```
if (AllMembersDead())
{
    for (float i = 0; i < waves; i++)
    {
        SpawnUntilFull();       // number of waves to be spawned
    }
    Destroy(position);
}
```

Here is the picture of the gameobject I destroy:

[image]

Here are the function for SpawnUntilFull() and AllMembersDead() if needed.

```
bool AllMembersDead()
{
    foreach(Transform childPositionGameObject in transform)
    {
        if (childPositionGameObject.childCount > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void SpawnUntilFull()
{
    Transform freePosition = NextFreePosition();
    if (freePosition)
    {
        GameObject enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, freePosition.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject; // Instantiate (spawning or creating) enemy prefab (as gameobject assures that what its returning to us is no normal object but rather a game object)
        enemy.transform.parent = freePosition; // the transform of whatever thing the enemy is attached to, and that would be the enemyFormation GameObject
    }

    if (NextFreePosition())
    {
        Invoke("SpawnUntilFull", spawnDelay);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It is in the Update function.

Answer (score 1):

I think your **AllMembersDead()** function returns false because the *childPositionGameObject* you're looking at is the TotalPositions gameobject,  hence **SpawnUntilFull()** is never called.
Try changing the function to point to the right parent, as such:

```
bool AllMembersDead()
{
    foreach(Transform childPositionGameObject in position)
    {
        if (childPositionGameObject.childCount > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I see, I think I understand what your trying to get at I ended up adding a single line of code above the foreach statement                               Transform allChildren = GetComponentInChildren<Transform>();                     Unfortunately that didn't change anything.